# update php page using ajax using post requests reload the page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, oracle

I am trying to change the content of my php web page using ajax as below 
the index.php page has input filed that call a function to executed on the button click but my problem is that the page is reload it

so i want to know what I am doing wrong??

Note that i am using the post requests to keep my data secure as w3schools.com recommended

**inexd.php** file code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Site Title</title>

</head>

<body align="left">

<div>
    <h4 align="left">Balance Enquiry</h4>
</div>

<form>
     <div>
        <label>Account Number </label>
        <input id="AccNum" type="text" name="AccNumInput">
        <button type="button" onclick="SendForm()">Search</button>
      </div>
</form>

<script>
function SendForm()
{
    alert("Hello! SendForm start");
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {

                document.getElementById("AccNum").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    };
        alert("Hello! going to send ajax");
        var x = xmlhttp.open("POST","AccData.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send(document.getElementById("AccNum").value);  // you want to pass the Value so u need the .value at the end!!!

        alert(document.getElementById("AccNum").value);
        alert("Hello! SendForm end");
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The **data.php** file code below

```
<?php

alert("Hello! php start processing");

$AccountNumber = $_POST['AccNum'];

$conn = oci_connect('admin', 'admin', 'localhost/JDT', 'AL32UTF8');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

alert("Hello! connected to oracle");

$sqlstr = 'SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,CUST_NAME,PHONE1 FROM customers where CUSTOMER_ID=:AccNum';

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sqlstr); // creates the statement

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':AccNum', $AccountNumber); // binds the parameter

oci_execute($stid); // executes the query

echo $AccountNumber;
/**
 *  THIS WHILE LOOP CREATES ALL OF YOUR HTML (its no good solution to echo data out like this)
 */
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td align=center>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid); // releases the statement
oci_close($conn); // closes the conneciton

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `<input type="submit" value="Search">` your sending the form the "old" way to the server not with Ajax!

```
<form>
     <div>
        <label>Account Number </label>
        <input id="AccNum" type="text" name="AccNuminput">
        <button type="button" onclick="sendForm()">Search</button>
      </div>
</form>
<script>
function sendForm(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //Execudted when finished and everything its Okay
                document.getElementById("AccNum").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "acc_data.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send("accNum="+document.getElementById("AccNum").value); // you want to pass the Value so u need the .value at the end!!!
    }


</script>
```

Then in your data.php you do not need any html you just need to process the the data that you received by the ajax post request(Session is also not needed for that) . In the `xmlhttp.responseText` you are receiving your answer from the server when the request is finished.

```
<?php

$accountNumber = $_POST['accNum'];// set a good variable name
$conn = oci_connect('admin', 'admin', 'localhost/JDT', 'AL32UTF8'); //setup connection
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR); // throws an error on connection error
}
$sqlstr = 'SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,CUST_NAME,PHONE1 FROM customers where CUSTOMER_ID=:ACCNUM'; // sql stirng
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sqlstr); // creates the statement
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':ACCNUM', $accountNumber); // binds the parameter
oci_execute($stid); // executes the query


/**
 *  THIS WHILE LOOP CREATES ALL OF YOUR HTML (its no good solution to echo data out like this)
 */
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td align=center>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid); // releases the statement
oci_close($conn); // closes the conneciton

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help.. that explained a lot of thinks that was not clear to me... please would you mind to teach me whats better to use instead of loop to create HTML ?

Comment: Youre welcome
i think the best solution is to create a JSON Object and return the json object back to the html page and then do the rest with javascript... but got step by step ... do not try to learn all technologies at the same time thats really hard.

Comment: okay then ill go step by step as you said.. one last think the data not get back from server the url changed to http://localhost/test/?AccNumInput=1000 but the result wont load and at the xmlhttp.send("accNum="+document.getElementById("AccNum").value)
is should be xmlhttp.send(document.getElementById("AccNum").value) because the value will be passed with string which should not be within the sql statement ?

Comment: in `xmlhttp.open("POST", "acc_data.php", true);' replace acc_data.php with the whole url for the php page you want to send the form.

Comment: I am using localhost and the file on same directory tird to pass it by this way //localhost/test/Acc_Data.php and by this way too F:\xampp\htdocs\test\Acc_Data.php wont work btw the url wont change to localhost/test/?AccNumInput=1000 when I press the button its only changes when I press enter keyboard button on the focus of input filed

Comment: I have updated the code with alert message all message appear except those after the call and at beginning of next page